# win32: get current DEVMODE of a monitor

Tags: python, winapi, monitor, pywin32

How can I get the current resolution in win32? I know I can use `GetMonitorInfo` to get the current bounding rectangle of the monitor, but how can I also get the bit-depth? Pretty much, how do I get the `DEVMODE` struct of a given monitor?

I'm using python and pywin32, so solutions addressing those specifically are nice, but just the winapi calls will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the EnumDisplayMonitors function mentioned in Dean's answer you need [GetDeviceCaps()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28VS.85%29.aspx). See parameter BITSPIXEL: it gives you the number of adjacent color bits for each pixel.

Comment: EnumDisplayMonitors didn't return a valid DC... but using `GetWindowDC` with `GetDeviceCaps` worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [EnumDisplayMonitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function, which calls a callback for each monitor and passes the rectangle and a device context (which includes the colour information).

pywin32 has [win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32api__EnumDisplayMonitors_meth.html), which appears to use EnumDisplayMonitors under the covers to return a list with the same details as I mentioned above.

Comment: How do I get color information from the device context? pywin32 returns the monitor handle, a device context, and a 4-tuple with the bounding area for the monitor, but the device context seems to be 0... assuming it's correct though, how do I get from the HDC to a color depth?